# jQuery get variable issue

Tags: jquery

I'm at beginning with jQuery. I want to get "moves" variable from this (http://sprunge.us/FdVb) jQuery library to print in an html page.

Comment: Are you trying to debug something? You could use Firebug to set a breakpoint wherever you need to see the variable.

Comment: @robbrit: I want simply know javascript code to get that variable and print it in an html page. @scobal: if answers don't satisfy me, why have I to accept?

Comment: as sv_in answered, you can't get the variable since it is a local variable. You'll have to modify the variable to be at either a global scope or as part of an object in order to access it.

Answer (score 0):

the `moves` variable is in the scope of a function, a local scope. Due to this, the variable cannot be accessed unless the variable is made a global variable or there is a getter function in that scope which can access and provide the variable variables to other functions in scope other than it.

Comment: thanks. can you write a solution to make the variable global and how to get it then for my scope?